# For a Riemannian covering map $\tilde M\rightarrow M$, any metric on $\tilde M$ invariant under deck transformations descends $M$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

This is a problem in [Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature (GTM176)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/038798271X), Chapter 3, Exercise 3.6. The problem states

> If $\pi : \tilde M \to M$ is a smooth covering map, and $\tilde g$ is any metric on $\tilde M$ that is invariant under all covering transformations, show that there is a unique metric $g$ on $M$ such that $\tilde g = \pi ^* g$.

I know the first step is to constructing $g$ by the pull-back of $\pi^{-1}$ at local coordinates of every points, then show that this definition would not conflict for different points show that for any two points $\tilde p_1, \tilde p_2 \in \tilde M$ satisfying $\pi (\tilde p_1) = \pi (\tilde p_2) = p$.

My idea is: if I can select a covering transformation $\varphi: \tilde M \to \tilde M$, such that $\varphi(p_1) = \varphi(p_2)$, then I can use $\pi^* = \varphi^* \circ \pi^*$ to draw the conclusion that the pullback of $g|_p$ at $p_1$ and $p_2$ are exactly $\tilde g|_{\tilde p_1}$ and $\tilde g|_{\tilde p_2}$.

However, I realized that I don't really know how to prove that such a covering transformation $\varphi$ really exists! The topic of covering map and covering transformations (seems to relating to differential and algebraic topology too much) is too unfamiliar to me. So do anyone know **how to prove:**

**If $\pi: \tilde M \to M$ is a covering map between smooth manifolds, then for every $\tilde p_1, \tilde p_2 \in \tilde M$ such that $\pi (\tilde p_1) = \pi (\tilde p_2) = p$, there exists a covering transformation (deck transformation) such that $\varphi(p_1) = p_2$?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition is correct: covering transformations need not always exist when you want them to.

And, in fact, the statement in your post is true only for [normal covering maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Normal_coverings) (also known as regular covering maps or Galois covering maps), meaning covering maps $\pi : \tilde M \to M$ having the property that for each $p \in M$, the deck transformation group of $\pi$ acts transitively on the fiber $\pi^{-1}(p)$.

For a covering map that is not normal, the statement is false. There exist examples of covering maps $\pi : \tilde M \to M$ that are not homeomorphisms for which the deck transformation group is trivial. Any Riemannian metric on $\tilde M$ is therefore invariant under all covering transformations, for the simple reason that the identity map is the only covering transformation. But it is far from true that any Riemannian metric on $\tilde M$ is the lift of a metric on $M$.

---

Here's one way you can corect the statement in your post to get a statement that is actually true.

Consider $U \subset M$ an open subset that is evenly covered by the map $\pi$, meaning that $\pi^{-1}(U)$ can be expressed as a union of pairwise disjoint collection $\{V_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ of open subsets $V_\alpha \subset \tilde M$, such that each restriction $\pi \mid V_\alpha : V_\alpha \to U$ is a diffeomorphism. For any $\alpha,\beta \in A$ there is a unique diffeomorphism $h:V_\alpha \to V_\beta$ such that $(\pi \mid V_\beta) \circ h = \pi \mid V_\alpha$. Let me refer to such a diffeomorphism $h$ as a *local deck transformation over $U$*.

The correct statement is that if $\tilde g$ is a metric on $\tilde M$, and if $\tilde g$ is invariant under every local deck transformation over every evenly covered open subset of $M$, then there is a unique metric $g$ on $M$ such that $\tilde g = \pi^* g$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your definition of "local deck transformation" indeed makes more sense in this content.

Comment: You're right, this is a mistake in the first edition. You should check out the [errata for the first edition](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/RM/). Or better yet, get the [second edition](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-91755-9), which has fewer errors and is a lot more complete.